# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm receiving a jquery (i believe) error that I cannot figure out.

The full error message in console is:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'
```

This is the snippet of code that is failing:

```
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
dataType:"json",
url:"viewapi.jsp",
success:function(images) {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var image = images[i];
        addItem(image.id, image.title);
    }
    $("#allimages").listview('refresh');
}
```

And this is the HTML it is trying to manipulate

```
    <div data-role="content" class="photolist"> 
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="allimages"></ul>
</div>
```

I'm not certain why this code does not work, or where the error is coming from.  Even if the get request returned nothing, it should error out before the line is it getting caught on

Comment: Have you loaded the `listview` widget code?

Comment: jquery-1.8.2.min.js is loaded by this point, yes

Comment: @Barmar You say widget?!? Is it in here: http://jquerymobile.com/download/?

Comment: I didn't know listview was a standard jQuery Mobile widget (I'm mainly familiar with jQuery and jQuery UI, and your question never mentioned Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listview function is presumably a plugin for jQuery. Has that plugin file been added to page in time? That error can mean a missing plugin.

Comment: Is jquery mobile loaded as well? I'm assuming thats the listview function that you're mentioning.

Comment: It was only being loaded conditionally, after checking if the browser was mobile.  Trying to load it always just to see what happens.